# Can Angular be used like AngularJS with any html support technology

Tags: angular, visualforce

We can use AngularJS on any HTML page by just including the  tag in it. Can we use Angular in such fashion? I want to use Angular with Salesforce Visualforce page

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely. You can.

Create a VisualForce page, but instead of populating it with VisualForce components, use it to load Angular application.

Let's assume you have an angular cli project and the **index.html** is like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SalesforceAngularDemo</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

You need to convert it into Salesforce like below,

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <title>SalesforceAngularDemo</title>
  <base href="/"></base>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.sftestassets, 'favicon.ico')}"></link>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.sftestassets, 'inline.bundle.js')}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.sftestassets, 'polyfills.bundle.js')}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.sftestassets, 'styles.bundle.js')}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.sftestassets, 'vendor.bundle.js')}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.sftestassets, 'main.bundle.js')}"></script>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

You need to upload the angular project as a static resource in Salesforce.

You can see the below links for details

[Building an angular application on Salesforce](https://medium.com/slalom-engineering/building-angular-applications-on-salesforce-29385df6a8af)

[Marrying Salesforce and Angular 2](https://medium.com/@watzon/marrying-salesforce-and-angular-2-94a1b2e54872)

And most importantly, there is an open source [GitHub project](https://github.com/watzon/salesforce-angular2-boilerplate) on the integration of Angular 2 with Salesforce,
you can also contribute there.